# Common docCursor() - ax 2012

Tags: axapta, x++

I'm moving some solutions and projects from ax 2009 to 2012 and I've found this method:

```
public Common docCursor()    
{
    Common docCursor;
    docCursor = super();
    if (docCursor.TableId == tablenum(InventDim))
    {
        docCursor = custPackingSlipTrans;
    }
    return docCursor;
}
```

I was reading about common but I can't really understand what that method does. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Common is ancestor of all tables in Axapta.  In this method:

We use ancessor of current class to get table variable:

```
    docCursor = super();
```

We don't know what table is it.  So we check if it is a instance of InventDim table:

```
    if (docCursor.TableId == tablenum(InventDim))
```

And if it is we overwrite this table variable by 'custPackingSlipTrans' variable.